# Is there a ColdFusion function that checks to see if a file on the web server is locked?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Is there a ColdFusion 10 function that checks to see if a file on the web server is locked?
I'm trying to upload a file and delete it or use it for other functions, but when I go to delete the file, the code is executing quicker than the web server can finish uploading it. I came to this conclusion by deleting an older file from the directory and it worked just fine.
Is there a ColdFusion function I can check to see if the file is unlocked? Otherwise, I'll get this error.

```
coldfusion.tagext.io.FileUtils$CouldNotDeleteFileException: 
ColdFusion could not delete the file D:\webServer\confusedDeer.txt 
for an unknown reason.
```

Comment: Can you post some code? We need to see what is actually happening, not what *seems* to be happening (which could be wrong or misleading)

Comment: no, but you can cfcatch that just as easily I guess.

Comment: Yes, but it sounds like the error may be a symptom of a bigger problem. Better to figure out what that is, rather than compounding the issue by trying to code around it.

Comment: I have seen this kind of error when I use a fileopen, then something crashes. The file seens remain open until the CF service is restarted. I would suggest you put the file open in a try/catch/finally code block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CFML? No. However you can check if you can write to or read a file before doing so via methods of [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Comment: boolean canRead()
Tests whether the application can read the file denoted by this abstract pathname.
boolean canWrite()
Tests whether the application can modify the file denoted by this abstract pathname.

Comment: But did you figure out *why* the file is locked? There are some operations that can lock a file, but this explanation does not sound right: *the code is executing quicker than the web server can finish uploading it*

Comment: ColdFusion not keeping a file open seems to be a popular problem. I never found out why the file is locked.